# UnicodeDecodeError sending an email with PDF attachment

Tags: django

I'm trying to send an email with a pdf attachment, but I get a UnicodeDecodeError when I execute `message.send()`.  How can I prevent this from happening?  The PDF is generated with [django-easy-pdf](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-easy-pdf/)

This is python 2.7.6.

Relevant code:

```
    pdf = open("stuff.pdf").read()
    message = EmailMessage(
        subject="This is a subject",
        body="This is your pdf",
        from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
        to=[email])

    message.attach('stuff.pdf', pdf, 'application/pdf')
    message.send(fail_silently=False)
```

And the exception:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError('utf8', '%PDF-1.4\r\n%\x93\x8c\x8b\x9e ReportLab Generated PDF document     http://www.reportlab.com\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<< /F1 2 0 R /F2 4 0 R >>\r\nendobj\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<< /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F1 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font >>\r\nendobj\r\n3 0 obj\r\n<<.....
```

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: Can you try `message.attach_file('stuff.pdf')`?

Comment: I can give it a try.  I'll have to create a temp file for it, there really is no .pdf file, it's all generated.

Comment: Ah, in that case you probably need to open the file in binary mode: `open("stuff.pdf", 'b')` and pass that object along (as it's not a text file).

Comment: use "with open(...) as f: ..."

Comment: Yeah, I those don't work.  `attach_file` basically just opens the file exactly like I'm doing, and then calls `self.attach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the email backend we were using: https://github.com/dstufft/django-postmark has a problem with sending attachments like that.  We've moved to mandrill and the problem is gone.